# How to prevent bash from extending ~ to full name of home dir on tab?

Tags: bash

In my bash I got the behavior like this:

when I type:

```
cd ~/projects/p   <press tab>
```

the bash extends the `~` part to the full name of my home dir:

```
cd /home/kender/projects/p
```

I remember it wasn't happening some time ago. Is that configurable in bash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably you're now using `/etc/bash_completion` – check if it's loaded by your profile or bashrc.

It contains a function `_expand` which replaces the tilde by the path “to avoid problems when $cur starting with a tilde is fed to commands and ending up quoted instead of expanded” (from the comments in the function).

If you still want to keep the tilde, you could have a look at the `_filedir` function.  Close to the top there's the line

```
_expand || return 0
```

Remove it or disable it with a `#` prefix.  This is a ugly hack, however, and you might run into the problems mentioned above.